# PHP specify the return type hints for a method

Tags: php

What is the correct syntax for me to specify the return type hints for a method?

For example, I have such a method:

```
private static function ConstructPDOObject($dbname) 
{
      $hostname =self::HOSTNAME;
        $username = self::USERNAME;
        $password = self::PASSWORD;
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        return $dbh;
}
```

And I want, whenever I call the above method, the IDE will show me the methods for PDO.

How to add the type hint?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Within [Aptana](http://aptana.com/), [PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/), [Zend Studio](http://shop.zend.com/en/zend-studio-for-eclipse.html) and other IDE's you can add type hinting to php methods as follows:

```
/**
 * Constructs a new PDO Object and returns it
 *
 * @param string $dbname name of the database to connect to
 * @return PDO connection to the database
 */
private static function ConstructPDOObject($dbname) 
{
      $hostname =self::HOSTNAME;
      $username = self::USERNAME;
      $password = self::PASSWORD;
      $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      return $dbh;
}
```

The class name is placed after the @return attribute of the documentation block to signify the return type of the method. E.g. In the case of your example method, *PDO* is the class name that is returned.  The additional description "connection to the database" is used to provide a meaningful description of the returned value to other developers, this is not required but is advised.

One of the great things about documenting your php methods in this manner, is that you can then generate documentation using either [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/) or [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/).

Comment: I was coming with the same question similar than Graviton's : your answer is a workaround using the IDE code analysis capabilities and not a PHP specification. Anyway, +1 because it works.

Comment: You can check the return type by pre-casting it before returning, but it only checks if the returned result can be casted to the specified type. See [php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php] (Thanks to StackOverflow user DhruvPathak)

Answer (score 24):

For future reference, this is implemented for **PHP 7**, with the following syntax (quoted from source):

```
function foo(): array {
    return [];
}
```

To answer your question now, as of PHP 7 (released around end of 2015) you will be able to do the following (as an example):

```
<?php

function ConstructPDOObject($hostname, $dbname, $username, $password): PDO 
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    return $dbh;
}
```

The specification also allows for type hinting within and against interfaces; for those of us interested in adhering to SOLID principles.

Source and more information: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types

Answer (score 5):

PHP doesn't support type hinting on return types. Perhaps you should add a documentation block declaring the return type and maybe your IDE will pick that up (I don't know if it will or not).

Comment: Confirmed with NetBeans 8.1! Thx for the clue

Answer (score 4):

The IDE hinting is done via comments.  Here is an example from one of my ZEND Front Plugins.

```
<?php

/**
 * Initializes Application wide authentication
 *
 * @author Lance Rushing
 * @since  2009-06-01
 * @param  Zend_Session $session
 * @return Zend_Auth  <--- gives IDE Hint
 */
protected function initAuth($session)
{
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    require_once 'AuthStorage.php';
    $auth->setStorage(new My_AuthStorage($session));
    return $auth;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Return type hints are only supplied by your IDE.  Zend studio and PDT support the PHPDocumentor style doc blocks.

http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.return.pkg.html